# StackOverflow while setting ListView.ItemsSource

Tags: c#, wpf, stack-overflow

So I have a simple struct `Point` with two doubles `X` and `Y`. I calculate an array of about three hundred of them and set that array as ItemsSource for a ListView in WPF. That call eventually throws a `StackOverflowException`.

De debugger breaks at the beginning of the `Equals` method in my struct, which I implemented like so (should it matter):

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
  if (obj is Point)
    return Equals(obj);

  return false;
}
public bool Equals(Point other)  // Implement IEquatable<T>
{
  return this.x == other.x && this.y == other.y;
}
```

If I change that to this:

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
  return false;
}
```

Nothing happens and the numbers get displayed. I really don't know what I did wrong here, so I don't know how to fix this. Any pointers?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The program is trying to call `Equals(object obj)` again because you are passing `obj` as an `object` even though it's a `Point`. So essentially that overload is calling itself again and again.

You have to cast `obj` to `Point` when you pass it in the inner call, so it'll call the `Equals(Point other)` method instead:

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
  if (obj is Point)
    return Equals((Point) obj);

  return false;
}
```

Comment: That solved it! Can't believe I made such a stupid mistake.. Thanks you for pointing it out.

Comment: @Saurabh: Thanks, I have somewhat of an affinity with method overloads.

Answer (score 5):

Just a quickie - an alternative way of writing the Equals(object) method is:

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
    return (obj is Point) && Equals((Point)obj);
}
```

(The first set of brackets isn't actually necessary, but I think it helps the readability.)